# Laravel - migrations

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I know I can run `artisan migrate` to execute my created migrations in my local environment, but:

How can I run migrations in a hosting, if I don't have command line? (this also applies to migrate:install command so I can make them available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it from your application:

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

Comment: ty :D i'm a total n00b at this, and need to deploy something :D. (accepting in 9min...)